# ImportError: cannot import name 'TOP' from 'tkinter' (C:\Users\abhay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, openfiledialog, filedialog

I am making a MP3 Player by using tkinter python. I need to use file dialog to select songs from that into the playlist.
But when I use
`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pygame


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('MP3 Player')
root.geometry('500x300')

#Initialize Pygame Mixer
pygame.mixer.init()

# Add One Song function
def addOneSong():
    song = fd.askopenfile
    print(song)
    


# Create a Playlist Box
songBox = tk.Listbox(root, bg="black", fg="green", width=60)
songBox.pack(pady=20)

# Define Player control Buttons
backButtonImg = tk.PhotoImage(file="Images/back50.png")
forwardButtonImg = tk.PhotoImage(file="Images/forward50.png")
playButtonImg = tk.PhotoImage(file="Images/play50.png")
pauseButtonImg = tk.PhotoImage(file="Images/pause50.png")
stopButtonImg = tk.PhotoImage(file="Images/stop50.png")

# Create Player Controls Frame
controlFrame = tk.Frame(root)
controlFrame.pack()

# Create Player Controls Buttons
backButton = tk.Button(controlFrame, image=backButtonImg, borderwidth=0)
forwardButton = tk.Button(controlFrame, image=forwardButtonImg, borderwidth=0)
playButton = tk.Button(controlFrame, image=playButtonImg, borderwidth=0)
pauseButton = tk.Button(controlFrame, image=pauseButtonImg, borderwidth=0)
stopButton = tk.Button(controlFrame, image=stopButtonImg, borderwidth=0)

backButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
stopButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
playButton.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
pauseButton.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)
forwardButton.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10)

# Create Menu
myMenu = tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=myMenu)

# Add Add Song Menu
addSongMenu = tk.Menu(myMenu)
myMenu.add_cascade(label="Add Songs", menu=addSongMenu)
addSongMenu.add_command(label="Add One Songs to Play", command=addOneSong)


root.mainloop()
```

`

In the above code
`from tkinter import filedialog as fd`
this create a error
as::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python - Tkinter\50MP3Player.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkinter import filedialog as fd
  File "C:\Users\abhay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 21, in <module>    from tkinter import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'TOP' from 'tkinter' (C:\Users\abhay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py)
PS F:\Python - Tkinter>
```

Pls Help to so that I can use file dialog

I tried different ways to import file dialog but all present the same error

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error with my Python 3.11.3.

Comment: What version of tkinter do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to recreate your error, but when you are calling "fd.askopenfile()" you don't completely call it or provide any argument values. The below correction works for me. I also included a supplemental link if you need additional information.

```
def addOneSong():
song = fd.askopenfile(mode='r',filetypes=[('MP3','*.mp3')])
print(song)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-askopenfile-function-in-tkinter/

Comment: I tried it but it also producing same error. I don't know why??